# Error with pow: "can't convert complex to float"

Tags: python, math

i have this problem with my Python code :

```
from math import *

m = pow(complex(1,2)*complex(3,0) + complex(1,0),complex(-1,0));
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Use tags wisely mate.

Comment: What `import`s are you using?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/zaAQVG) Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem, See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Also make your title meaningful.

Comment: Did you try googling the error message?

Comment: And what are the other four variables?  Get this down to the minimum number of lines (3? 4?), and then copy and paste the entire Python script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `from math import *`. This shadows the built-in `pow` with a [version that doesn't support complex numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html?highlight=math#math.pow).

```
>>> pow(1+1j, 1)
(1+1j)
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(1+1j,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

`from <x> import *` is usually considered bad practice, and cases like this are why.

Instead, you should use `import math`, and reference all your math functions as, e.g. `math.sqrt`

Alternatively, you can use `**` instead of `pow`:

```
>>> 1j ** 2
(-1+0j)
```